# How can I assign the random number from array to value?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, random

I have a problem with arrays and assigning them to values like float. Here is my code

```
System.out.print("Please enter the number of iteration: ");
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inumber = scn.nextInt(); // i get the iteration number

        Random rnd = new Random();
        float x = -10 + rnd.nextFloat() * 20; // i created random number between 10 and -10
        System.out.println("My x = " +x);

            float[] xarray = new float[4]; // created my test array
            Random arrayrnd = new Random();


        for (int i=0;i<inumber;i++) { // created a for loop with that number

            for (int j = 0; j<xarray.length;j++) {

                xarray[j] = arrayrnd.nextFloat(); // also created random for array and assigned them
            }

            Arrays.sort(xarray); // i sorted the array
            xarray[0] = x; // i tried to assign the smallest number to x but didn't work

            System.out.println("t="+i+" My new x = " +x);
```

Also here is my output :

`Please enter the number of iteration: 2
My x = -6.2841988
t=0 My new x = -6.2841988
t=1 My new x = -6.2841988`

I just don't understand why my x hasn't changed even though I tried to assign the x with the new value. I want my x to change in every turn of the loop and got the the smallest number of the array. But it seems like x never wants to move. I'm sorry if my code is complicated or if I have any mistake. Happy coding!

Comment: You should move `float x = -10 + rnd.nextFloat() * 20;` inside your loop if you want it to change

Comment: you are using the same x all the time, not the new value

Comment: `xarray[0] = x; // i tried to assign the smallest number to x but didn't work` .----you are not assigning the smallest to x, but the vise visa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want **assign TO x**, you should do:

```
x = xarray[0];
```

Instead of:

```
xarray[0] = x;
```